# Search MySQL column for similar words

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a way to prevent MySQL from differentiating b/w strings such as "Kill Bill: Vol 2" and "Kill Bill: Vol II"? I am creating a web-scraper that scrapes movies from different websites and stores them in the database. Since different websites use different titles many a times, is there a way to ignore these minor differences in strings?

Soundex sounds promising but it is not so effective for non-English strings.

Another example: "Padmaavat" and "Padmavat". Soundex might be effective here but I need a more reliable solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no builtin function in MySQL for that (i.e. for considering strings  `"Vol.2"` and `"Vol II"` to be a *match*.)

There's a builtin `SOUNDEX` function, but that only does what it does. That might be part of a solution.

You might be able to implement string matching algorithm(s) as roll-your-own MySQL stored program(s).  But, ugghhh. String matching algorithms are probably better implemented in a layer other than the relational database.